# Why can I assign an Int to a String without compiler error?

Tags: c++

All these lines compile and run, with nothing printed in the output:

```
  std::string ss{6}; 
  ss=7;
  std::cout << "ss " << ss << "\n";
```

I do not see any referenced constructor for `std::string` that would suggest it can coerce an integer to a string, so why does the compiler not complain?

Comment: May find the [assignment operator documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D) helpful.

Comment: The answers so far don't mention `std::string ss{6};`, which calls the constructor taking `initializer_list<char>` .

Comment: `basic_string& operator=( CharT ch );` - Wait... what? What a stupid overload.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath much about `string` looks bad with the benefit of 20-25 years of hindsight

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "problem" is that a `std::string` is assignable from `char` and `int` is implicitly convertible to `char`.

Take a look at [std::basic_string::operator=](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D) point (4):

```
basic_string& operator=( CharT ch );
```

---

EDIT

As stated in [M.M's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38048208/why-can-i-assign-an-int-to-a-string-without-compiler-error/38048285#comment63535952_38048208), `std::string ss{6};` calls the constructor taking `initializer_list<char>` (see [`std::basic_string::basic_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) point `(9)`)... and the problem resurfaces.

Comment: Wow, I can definitely see why some languages remove possibly of these errors by not allowing implicit conversions between types.

Comment: @JXB: To be fair, the bigger problem here is that C doesn't have a character type; it instead stores numerical codes for the characters in an integral type.

Answer (score 1):

It's the

```
basic_string& operator=( CharT ch );
```

So the `int` is implicitly being converted to a `char`.

Try assigning the value `65`. Prints `A`

Answer (score 1):

The line `ss=7` does not call a constructor, but the assignment operator `=()`.

`std::string` *does* have an assignment operator that takes a `char`, and your value 7 is converted into a `char`, then the `string& operator= (char c);` is called for that value. Your string will contain the ASCII BELL character.

See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator=/) for more info.